# DNS query tool (host(1) or nslookup(1) replacement)

Tags: linux, command-line, dns, unix

I'm looking for a command-line tool that can query a name server for an IP address.

Something like `host(1)` as provided by BIND.

```
# query the name server at 4.2.2.4 for the name example.org
$ host example.org 4.2.2.4
```

I found Unbound which [provides a `host(1)` replacement](https://unbound.net/documentation/unbound-host.html) but alas, it cannot query custom name servers AFAICT.

I know BIND provides tools that do just that but I would like to avoid those if possible. Bonus points if it is packaged on Debian.

Comment: Shipping with most distributions (or at least being available via their repos): `dig example.org @4.2.2.4` or `nslookup example.org 4.2.2.4`?

Comment: Don't both of those come from BIND?

Comment: Definitely not. I have no `bind` installed on my workbench, still I have all 3 available. Let me write up an answer.

Comment: @Izzy https://packages.debian.org/jessie/dnsutils "Depends: libbind9-90"

Comment: Yes, see my answer. Same for `dig`, as they both ship in the same package. But they only require that one library, not the entire bind server package. Is "not depending on bind or its libraries in any way" a requirement for the software you're looking for? You didn't say so :) // PS: Related on Unix&Linux: [alternative to nslookup in rhel7?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120710/alternative-to-nslookup-in-rhel7)

Comment: I believe I stated that in the final paragraph. (The thing is, I'd like to rid my system of the BIND libraries and the security updates they seemingly require every three days. I decided to not mention that for a fear of turning my question into a rant.)

Comment: Ah, sorry – missed that line ("I would like to avoid those if possible"). Sorry, but I'm not aware of any other alternatives *not* relying on bind libraries. Oh, wait... Updating my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `getent`. See `getent --help`.

```
$ getent hosts google.com
172.217.194.139 google.com
172.217.194.102 google.com
172.217.194.100 google.com
172.217.194.101 google.com
172.217.194.138 google.com
172.217.194.113 google.com
```

Ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120710/alternative-to-nslookup-in-rhel7?newreg=df3c1f65191748f8873c294bffad2fde

Comment: 'getent' seams to be always available on the most basic installation, being part of package 'libc-bin' on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or 'glibc-common' on RHEL 7.9.

Comment: not sure, but most probably

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried and don't have Debian box, but there is an alternative to bindutils called `ldns` which provides a utility called `drill` that is supposed to work similar to `dig`.  `ldnsutils` should be available as a debian pacakge and might do what you want.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that one. Package is available on Wheezy and Jessie both, good find! And no dependency on bind libraries listed. Syntax shows it completely meets the requirements: `drill [ OPTIONS ] name [ @server ] [ type ] [ class ]` :)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line) solutions available on Linux. Several of them come even pre-installed, but most of them are at least available via the standard repositories. Note that I'm also using the Unbound name server in my local network here :)

#### nslookup

This tool ships with the `dnsutils` package – which in fact is described as *Clients provided with BIND,* but definitely does not require bind itself (though it uses one of its libraries, `libbind`). As you requested, it supports an optional parameter to specify which name server to use (by default it checks which one is configured with your system):

```
nslookup example.org 4.2.2.4
```

would request the IP of `example.org` from a name server listening at port 53 at `4.2.2.4`. There's an interactive command-line interface as well, and you can specify which type of address you're looking for – e.g. `type=mx` for the SMTP MX records of a domain, or `type=ns` for the name servers.

#### dig

As `nslookup` was declared "deprecated" a while ago, today one should use `dig`. By default, `dig` produces much more detailed output. The syntax here would be:

```
dig example.org @4.2.2.4
```

for the same task described above. And again, specifying a name server is optional. Interestingly, the `dig` tool comes with the very same package, at least on Ubuntu: `dnsutils`.

#### dnsip

This candidate seems to be completely independent from any bind library. It belongs to the [djbdns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html) name server which was written from the scratch for exactly the same reasons you're looking after a replacement to bind, and is described e.g. [in this article](https://www.linux.com/news/djbdns-alternative-bind-0). You can find it in the Ubuntu repositories as `udns-utils`, the same on Debian Jessie (Wheezy seems not to have it). But unfortunately, `dnsip` does not support specifying the name server at the command line.